# Spring Reactive serverWebExchange unable to get secure cookie

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cookies, spring-webflux

I have a Rest controller in Spring Reactive defined as below:

```
@PostMapping("/a/b/load")
public Mono<Object> loadProductToMachine(@RequestBody ProductRequest productRequest,
                                 ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
   //body code is ignored.
}
```

I am unable to get cookie information from the serverWebExchange when the cookie is in the following format

```
SESSION={{sid}}; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;
```

However, when the "Secure" is removed from the cookie, I am able to get the session id from the serverWebExchange.

```
SESSION={{sid}}; Path=/; HttpOnly;
```

How can I solve this problem? I need "Secure" field in the cookie. I send the request from Postman in my local environment.

Comment: Are you using a secure channel aka `https://` for your endpoint?

Comment: No, I am sending the request from my local environment so it starts with http://.

Comment: That does not work by design: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cookie You could however set https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded header to make the server think the client is using a secure connection. But most likely the client (depending on what you use) will not send a secure cookie over an insecure connection.